# Counting Records in a Form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Ok we know that `Count` will not count null values.  So ...

*qty_rec* is a numeric field.

```
=Count(Nz([qty_rec],0)<1)
```

This is what I have for my Control Source on a textbox.

It returns the total number of records rather than the 5 that are null or zero.

What I need is a count of items that do not have a received quantity or a zero quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to count the number of records where *qty_rec* is Null, consider `Sum` of an `IIf` expression.

```vb
=Sum(IIf(IsNull([qty_rec]), 1, 0))
```

If the goal is actually count of zero or Null, use this instead:

```vb
=Sum(IIf(Nz([qty_rec], 0) = 0, 1, 0))
```

If you prefer `Count` instead of `Sum`, this should give you the same result as the second example:

```vb
=Count(IIf(Nz([qty_rec], 0) = 0, 1, Null))
```

Comment: Thank you, that does in fact work.  You're too fast though, I updated the question.  I need a value of zero counted as well.

Comment: I made note of the changes you made to the original post, I will incorporate in future posts.  Thank you.

Comment: I rephrased that one piece to *"rather than the 5 that are null or zero"* because that seemed clearer to me.  I trusted you would let me know if I mangled your meaning.  :-)  The other changes were more like just  cosmetic IMO.